# Python Pandas check cells for a range of numbers copy or skip if not there

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I would use pandas isin or iloc functions but the excel format is complex and there are sometimes data followed by cols of no info, and the main pool of entries are cols with up to 3 pieces of data in a cell with only a '|' to separate them. Some of the cells are missing a number and I want to skip those but copy the ones with them.

Above is my current code. I have a giant excel with thousands of entries and worse, the column/rows are not neat. There are several pieces of data in each column cell per row. What I've noticed is that a number called 'tail #' is missing in some of them. What I want to do is search for that number, if it has it then copy that cell, if it does not then go to the next column in the row. Then repeat that for all cells. There is a giant header, but when I transformed it into CSV, I removed that with formatting. This is also why I am looking for a number because there are several headers. for example, years that say like 2010 but then several empty columns till the next one maybe 10 cols later. Also please not that under this header of years are several columns of data per row that are separated by two columns with no info. Also, the info in a column looks like this, '13|something something|some more words'. If it has a number as you see, I want to copy it. The numbers seem to range from 0 to no greater than 30. Lastly, I'm trying to write this using pandas but  I may need a more manual way to do things because using isin, and iloc was not working.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import os.path as op
from openpyxl import workbook
import re


def extract_export_columns(df, list_of_columns, file_path):
    column_df = df[list_of_columns]
    column_df.to_csv(file_path, index=False, sep="|")
#Orrginal file
input_base_path = 'C:/Users/somedoc input'
main_df_data_file = pd.read_csv(op.join (input_base_path, 'som_excel_doc.csv '))

#Filter for tailnumbers
tail_numbers = main_df_data_file['abcde'] <= 30
main_df_data_file[tail_abcd]
#iterate over list
#number_filter = main_df_data_file.Updated.isin(["15"])
#main_df_data_file[number_filter]
#print(number_filter)
#for row in main_df_data_file.values:
    #for value in row:
       # print(value)
        #print(row)
        # to check the condition

# Product of code
output_base_path = r'C:\Users\some_doc output'
extract_export_columns(main_df_data_file,
                        ['Updated 28 Feb 18 Tail #'],
                    op.join(output_base_path, 'UBC_example3.txt'))
```

The code I have loads into csv, and successfully creates a text file. I want to build the body function to scan an excel/csv file to copy and paste to a text file data that contains a number.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1stXxgqBeo_sGksVYL9HHdn2IflFL_bb8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO! As currently formatted this question is pretty confusing - could you give a sample of your input and desired output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a short text copy of your CSV that is able to recreate your problem with your code. We would then be able to copy/paste it and test your code. i.e. copy say 10 lines of the CSV and show what the output SHOULD be that you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added a google drive link to an abridged excel file. Please note this is an xlsx, but in my code it is converted to a CSV then outputed as txt file. Also as an output, my goal is to scan to see if a number is present, if so, then copy that column. If not, then skip over it. Please note the orrignal excel has 40+ columns, and 300 rows.

Comment: Ive got most of the code written. All I'm missing now is a way to write straight to a text file. I have ways of getting it to a text but im using isin and I can print my results but to create the text file as you see in the above question doesn't work. Any suggestions? Afterwards, Ill post what I  have as an answer.